# Story of two HP laptop chargers

Tags: laptop, power, charger

I have two 65w HP laptop charger with 19.5V rated output voltage and 3.33A output current. When I use a voltmeter/digital multi-meter output voltage is showing as 19.5 on both chargers, but the problem is one charges the laptop, but another one does not. Why is second charger not charging the laptop? And how can I trouble shoot and fix the issue.

Comment: One is defective, voltage measurement was taken when the power supply is not under any load (current draw), when you connect it the voltage may be dropping below a charging voltage threshold for the laptop, most likely it is defective, nothing you can do.

Comment: Ok, and yes, voltage measurement was taken when there was no load.

Comment: You could try cutting open the sealed PS to satisfy your curiosity, but they're not easily fixed. On the other hand, a universal laptop PS that includes 19.5 V output and *at least 3.33 A* costs about US$20, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/Belker-Universal-Charger-Notebook-Ultrabook/dp/B014RCSHK6/ref=sr_1_10